# How to simplify this PHP conditional statement?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand a simple / better way of coding something like this php conditional statement.

```
<?php if (count($foo_bar) > 1) : ?>

    <div class="myDiv1">
      Hello!
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (count($foo_bar) == 1) : ?>

    <div class="myDiv2">
      Goodbye!
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Looking for example, and explanation as to why it may be better. Thanks!

Comment: nested ternary. tricky but wicked

Comment: @KhorneHoly Whilst you're right that CR will happily review working code, this would be completely Off-Topic because it's example code. CR only reviews actual implementations.

Comment: @Kaz thank you for this additional information, I'm not an active user there, so I'm not familiar what's exactly on-topic there.

Comment: @KhorneHoly That's quite alright. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Well in this example you could just do an else instead of the second if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply in this specific situation you dont need the second if as it can be accomplished with a simple `if else`

```
<?php if (count($foo_bar) > 1) : ?>

    <div class="myDiv1">
      Hello!
    </div>

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="myDiv2">
      Goodbye!
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Devil's advocate, but what if count($foo_bar) is 0?

Comment: Well I wondered that, but as the existing code, See my cateat (_in this specific situation_) there is nothing to cope with that situation either

Comment: Fair point, I just thought that if the behaviour was "do nothing",  it would need preserving as do nothing. Like I said devil's advocate, I can't really see where you would want to use it without $foo_bar being set with a countable value anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
     $class = 'myDiv2'; 
     $msg = 'GoodBye!';
     if (count($foo_bar) > 1) {
       $class = 'myDiv1';
       $msg = 'Hello!';
     }
?>

    <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
     <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an elseif like below. A bit more compact than the 2 statements.

```
<?php if (count($foo_bar) == 1) : ?>
<div class="myDiv2">
  Goodbye!
</div>
<?php     elseif(count($foo_bar) > 1): ?>
<div class="myDiv1">
  Hello!
</div>
<?php     endif; ?>
```

Comment: Bad formatting, so not all my code was shown. Naincy's answer is better though, mine still has too many repeated elements

Answer (score 1):

First, you should the count function only once.
Second, reduce the duplicated HTML blocks.

```
<?php 
$countFooBar = count($foo_bar);
if ($countFooBar == 1){
    $message = 'Goodbye! !';
    $cssClass = 'class1';
}elseif( $countFooBar > 1){
    $message = 'Hello!'
    $cssClass = 'class2';
}
?>

<div class="<?php echo $cssClass ?>">
  <?php echo $message; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Except for good or bad reasons the class used in the DIV is also different in the question!

Comment: Now it looks pretty much like @Naincy answer